# Is the source file size smaller than the executable file size?

Tags: data-compression

Wondering if compilation increases file size in general, is the source file size smaller than the executable file size?

Comment: This is something you can easily try at home, if you're in the possession of a compiler.

Comment: Never think *data compression* disregarding *decompression*. When thinking of compilation (or even translating between a somewhat verbose natural language and a terse one) in this context, does it have to be *lossless*? There is a wide variety of executable file formats, machine languages, programming languages, coders.

Answer (score 1):

This is heavily dependent on the source language, target language, compiler, etc...

In general, it is possible the size of the compiled code to be both larger and smaller than the source code (but not simultaneously :p)

For example, on my machine, the following code compiles to an executable of 16456 bytes (compiled with g++ with size optimization `-Os`)

```
int main() {return 0;}
```

The following code also results in an executable of exactly the same size (16456 bytes) but its source uses 32670 bytes:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    if(i==0) return 0;
    else if(i==1) return 1;
    else if(i==2) return 2;
    [...]
    else if(i==1023) return 1023;
    else if(i==1024) return 1024;
    else return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the libraries used were linked in. If you statically link many libraries in you’ll end up with a much bigger executable. So the executable can easily exceed the size of the source code, but the individual object files (pre-linking) that go with the code just compiled may be smaller.

EDIT:

Some others considerations apart from library linkage of why "it depends":

- Comments don’t get written to the code or data sections of the
  executable.
- Compiling with debug yields larger files.
- Executables have some overhead as they have instructions for the loader.
- Instructions are system-dependent, e.g, 64-bit will take up more room than 32-bit
- Some languages are more verbose than others.

For example, here we compile an empty main() to illustrate.

```
$ cat empty.c
main(){}
$ gcc -g3 -c empty.c -o debug.o
$ gcc -g0 -c empty.c -o nodebug.o
$ gcc -g0 -m32 -c empty.c -o 32bit.o
```

Source code is identical, but but the 32-bit object file is smaller than the 64-bit, and the object with debug is larger than the one without.

```
$ stat -c "%n %s" *.o *.c
32bit.o 490
debug.o 12611
nodebug.o 720
empty.c 8
```

Another example: compile this other file that has a lot of comments. Our 616,334 byte source code compiles to 490 bytes of object file.

```
$ gcc -g0 -m32 -c bigcomment.c -o bigcomment.o
$ stat -c "%n %s" *.o *.c
bigcomment.o 490
bigcomment.c 616334
```

Comment: I was more wondering about compression in the logic itself. So, when all libraries are included in the source file (no libraries are used). It is a very basic question, wondering something like "is uncompiled logic compressed relative to the compiled program?"